# session maintain using struts2 and hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I need to know how to maintain session for one form and multiple input[Name,City,Country] using Struts2 and finally data will stored to database using hibernate.

This form have two buttons:

- add (stored to session);
- Submit (stored to database).
- First, enter the form details [name city and country] and click add button data will store to session.
- Second, enter the details for same and now click add.
- Third, enter same form details but now click submit button all details (first second & third) will stored to database using hibernate.

pls help me to solve dis...

Person.java :

```
 @Entity
    public class Person {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;
        private String name;
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

PersonAction.java:

```
public class PersonAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

      private Person person = new Person();
     // Database base=new Database();

      public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
      }

      public void setPerson(Person person){
        this.person = person;
      }

      private Map<String, Object> session;

      public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session){
        this.session = session;
      }

      public String execute() { //Create persons
        List<Person> personList = (List<Person>) session.get("personList");
        for (Person p : personList)
        Database.saveData(this);
        personList.clear();
        return SUCCESS;
      }

      public String add() { //Add person
        List<Person> personList = (List<Person>) session.get("personList");
        if (personList == null) {
          personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
          session.put("personList", personList);
          System.out.println("Successfully added");
        }
        personList.add(person);
        return SUCCESS;

      }

    }
```

Database.java:

```
public class Database {
public static int saveData(PersonAction personAction){
        SessionFactory sf=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sf.openSession();
        Transaction tran=session.beginTransaction();
    int i=(Integer)session.save(personAction);
    tran.commit();
    session.close();
    return i;

    }
}
```

struts.xml:

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="person" class="org.PersonAction">
            <result>/person.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="person" class="org.PersonAction" method="add">
            <result>/person.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

index.jsp:

```
<s:form action="person">
    <s:textfield label="Enter your name" name="name"/>
    <s:submit value="Add person" method="add"/>
    <s:submit value="Create persons"/>
</s:form>
```

person.jsp:

```
<body>
<s:property value="#session.name"/>
</body>
```

Comment: ..i need complete source code... that things are bad.. what did you try to do?

Comment: see the update:first  im new to struts2 can u help me to solve dis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all read [Best Practices When Using SessionAware](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/http-session)

I will give you hints, Struts2 follow `MVC pattern` (or a variation of this pattern). So you have your Presentation layer, there you send a event to your Controller (PersonAction) and here you have to communicate with your model (Business Layer DataBase,Person) , model returns or not something to the controller and the controller decide what to show.

Your problem is that you are sending `PersonAction` to your `DataBase`  , you have to send `Person` that is mapped with hibernate :).
And try not using static methods for this things cause if you are in a concurrent application many users will access to that method `saveData`

This is bad

```
 for (Person p : personList)
            Database.saveData(this);
```

You have to do something like this

```
Database.saveData(personList);
```

And in Database class define a method

```
public static int saveData(List<Person> person)
```

Also in your `Person` class you have to map name property

**NOTE** I don`t recommend using static method for this kind of things

Answer (score 0):

use the following methods in the action class

```
/**
     * Convenience method to get the request.
     * @return current request
     */
    protected HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    return ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method to get the response.
     * @return current response.
     */
    protected HttpServletResponse getResponse() {
    return ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method to get the session. This will create a session if one
     * doesn't exist.
     * @return the session from the request (request.getSession()).
     */
    protected HttpSession getSession() {
    return getRequest().getSession();
    }
```

and u can use this code inside execute method

```
 getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("projectData", scheduleData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your SessionFactory as follows.

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Ruchi: im using annotation in hibernate so we change to AnnotationConfiguration() ...this s not my problem :(

Comment: ohh then my suggestion not helpful to you

Comment: not lik that man...in hibernate when we using annotation the configuration details will change to = SessionFactory sf=new AnnotationConfiguration().Configure.buildSessionFactory();                        if u not using annotation den the configuration is=   SessionFactory sf=new Configuration().Configure.buildSessionFactory();  dis question was about struts2 Session(sessionAware) :)